# Laravel's Session Handler does not invoke it's destroy functions

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm trying to add additional functionality when the user's session expires. I need data from the user's session before the Session Handler discards it (it's discarded before middleware and unavailable).

I added logs inside the Laravel's native `Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler.php`, however neither the `destroy()` or `gc()` functions get fired upon session expiry.

`FileSessionHandler` with only the added logs:

```
namespace Illuminate\Session;
...
class FileSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{ 
  ...

  public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $path, $minutes)
  {
    Log::debug('within FileSessionHandler __construct()');
    ...
  }

  public function open($savePath, $sessionName) {
    Log::debug('within FileSessionHandler open()');
    ...
  }

  public function close() {
    Log::debug('within FileSessionHandler close()');
    ...
  }

  public function read($sessionId) {
    Log::debug('within FileSessionHandler read()');
    ...
  }

  public function write($sessionId, $data) {
    Log::debug('within FileSessionHandler write()');
    ...
  }

  public function destroy($sessionId) {
    Log::debug('within FileSessionHandler destroy()');
    ...
  }

  public function gc($lifetime) {
    Log::debug('within FileSessionHandler gc()');
    ...
  }
}
```

`laravel.log` upon refreshing after session expiry:

```
[2021-03-23 20:51:30] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler read()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:30] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler write()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:36] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler construct()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:36] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler read()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:36] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler write()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:36] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler construct()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:36] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler read()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:37] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler write()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:37] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler construct()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:37] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler read()  
[2021-03-23 20:51:38] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler write()  
[2021-03-23 20:52:54] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler construct()  
[2021-03-23 20:52:54] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler read()  
[2021-03-23 20:52:54] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler write()  
[2021-03-23 20:52:54] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler construct()  
[2021-03-23 20:52:54] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler read()  
[2021-03-23 20:52:54] stage.DEBUG: within FileSessionHandler write()
```

`config\session.php`:

```
'driver' => 'file',
...
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

Does anyone know why `destroy()` and `gc()` are never fired, or where the session is actually being discarded?

Comment: How are you controlling the session expiry?

Comment: @apokryfos I have it set in `config\session.php`:


`'driver' => 'file', ... 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),`

Comment: Try setting `'lottery' => [1, 1]` that *should* trigger `gc` at the end of every request. I think `destroy` is only ever triggered manually via e.g. `session()->regenerate(true)`.

Comment: @apokryfos That did it, now `gc()` is being triggered! However it fires on every request like you mentioned.

I want a function that fires only on the user's session expiry to delete some records in a table. Do you know of a solution?

Only thing I can think of is setting the built-in `lifetime` to infinite and then doing it all from middleware, appending time to a timestamp in the session to mimic the built-in idle functionality (expire after X time from last request).

Comment: I think you need to find a different approach to this like adding a "valid until" timestamp on the records in the table and extending it on every user request. The problem is the session of a user will expire after X time of user inactivity so when `gc` is called it's called to clean up expired sessions of other users not the session of the current user which just had activity

Comment: OK I'll implement something like that. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discovery provided by @apokryfos, the Session Handler is not designed for the current user but for cleanup of other users.

In order to perform database modifications based on the session expiry of a user, there could be either:

- a CRON job/provider to perform database modifications based on a timestamp of a record
- middleware that fires while the session data you need is
  still available (before the Session Handler deleted the session).